# How to fit a curve with a circle with matlab?

Tags: matlab, graphics, curve-fitting

I would like to fit the curve bellow with a circle in a certain range with matlab.
I want to fit this curve from x=0,1 to x=0,5 and to get the radius of the circle.

Do you have any ideas how to do that with matlab?
[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have any ideas how to do it manually? Or in any other language?

Comment: I don't know how to do it manually,i'm new in matlab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I consider this as a least square minimization problem. You minimize the norm of the vector function, `[f1,f2,...fn]` with respect to  `x0`, `y0`, and `r`, where `fi(x0,y0,r) = (xi-x0)^2 + (yi-y0)^2 - r^2`. Here, `xi` and `yi` represent your data, and `i=1..n`.

Then first you create a vector function

```
function [ f ] = circle_fun( x0, y0, r, xdata, ydata, n )

f = zeros(n,1);
for i=1:n
    f(i) = abs((x0-xdata(i))^2 + (y0-ydata(i))^2 - r^2);
end
end
```

And use least square minimization function of MATLAB

```
f = @(inputs) circle_fun(inputs(1),inputs(2),inputs(3), xdata, ydata, n);
v0 = [0.1, 0.1, 0.1];
[v_opt,resnorm] = lsqnonlin(f,v0);
```

`v0` is an initial guess and `v_opt` is a solution vector that has `x0`, `y0`, and `r` inside.

Answer (score 1):

Besides using [the equation for a circle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle#Equations), one could do it manually by calculating the mean center of all points in the (x,y) plane, and then calculating the mean distance between  this center and all points.